# How to use the same express routes and the same mongo schema for different collections/model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

At the moment I have the following setup

`models/sourceModel.js`

```
var mongoose =  require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const sourceModel = new Schema({
    title: { type: String   },
    // and lots more
})
module.exports =  {
    Books: mongoose.model('Books', sourceModel),
    Videos: mongoose.model('Videos', sourceModel)
}
```

Then the two different routes **that are exactly the same**

`./routes/booksRoutes.js`

```
var {Books} = require("../models/sourceModel");
const Router = express.Router();
Router
.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Books.find({}, ...);
})
//more complex routes
```

`./routes/videosRoutes.js`

```
var {Videos} = require("../models/sourceModel");
const Router = express.Router();
Router
.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Videos.find({}, ...);
})
//more complex routes
```

`./routes/index.js`

```
API.use("/videos", require("./videosRoutes"));
API.use("/books", require("./booksRoutes"));
```

As I'm trying to show, the only thing that changes is this

```
    Books: mongoose.model('Books', sourceModel),
    Videos: mongoose.model('Videos', sourceModel)
```

I want to remove `/videosRoutes.js`, rename `/booksRoutes.js` to `/Routes.js` and somehow in `./routes/index.js` provide the same routes, the same schema, but different model and route name names.

Comment: Where does the Margin model come from?

Comment: @LuisOrbaiceta Typo, as I was trying to simplify it, I should read `Books` - I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a model in a dynamic way like this:

```
Router
.get("/", (req, res) => {
  mongoose.model(`${req.path}`).find({}, ...);
})
```

Note: Don´t forget to capitalize this path to match the model name and to do the correct imports